# Please change the deployment mode to exploded archive in Server Editor

Tags: java, spring, maven, web, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to deploy an EAR in weblogic10.3.6 application server. My ear module contains a web application module and and a jar module. When I'm deploying ear to weblogic server this is showing error -

```
'D:/Workspace/test-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml'='/WEB-INF/web.xml'

WebLogic split source deployment only supports resource folder mapping 
to EAR or web content root. Please change the deployment mode
to exploded archive in Server Editor.
```

How can I set the deployment mode of Weblogic server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Eclipse IDE, please right click to web project:

> Properties -> Deployment Assembly

and check your deployment assembly list.

For example I have this list in my Deployment Assembly:

```
src/main/java      | WEB-INF/classes
src/main/resources | WEB-INF/classes
src/main/...       | WEB-INF/web.xml
```

I deledet web.xml row because the WebLogic supported WEB-INF/classes. [Here is](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1556828) an explanation:

> If you are mapping external folders to web resources in Deployment
>   Assembly, NOT all the mappings are supported, only resource folder
>   mapping to EAR or web content root are supported in split source. (In
>   your case, mapping to '/WEB-INF/classes/' should be supported, which
>   is a bug we will fix in future release)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Deployment mode in the propertis of the Weblogic server in the Server View. Right click on the Weblogic server and navigate to Properties -> Weblogic -> Publishing.

The default deployment mode is *Virtual application* which is the better option if you want the full debugging and Hot Swap functionality.

So instead of changing the deployment mode you should have a look at your *Deployment Assembly* settings of your application and remove any ambigous source definitons (as described in the other answer).